# How to get the age in regex

Tags: regex

```
 My username is Ajay. I am 20 years old.
 My username is atb00ker. I am 40 years old.
 My username is 394843. I am 22 years old.
```

How can I use regex in Javascript to extract the age?

Comment: Which language are you looking for

Comment: Hi, it's cool you started looking into regex! here are some tips, there are plenty of online resources, have you tried using them? for example: https://pythex.org is very easy to use and understand, a bit more complicated ones is this one https://regex101.com and of course https://www.regular-expressions.info with all the regex needed. some tips about asking question here, it'd be much easier to help you if you tell us what is it that you tried to do, and what kind of trouble you have, this way we can point you in the right direction! try reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want the syntax, any language would work... I think they have same syntax. @Krishna,

Comment: And I just want to extract the age, @AvishayCohen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this pattern:

```
/(am\s)(\d{1,2})/
```

```js
var str1 = 'My username is Ajay. I am 20 years old.';
var str2 = 'My username is atb00ker. I am 40 years old.'
var str3 = 'My username is 394843. I am 22 years old.';

var pattern = /(am\s)(\d{1,2})/;

console.log(str1.match(pattern)[2]);
console.log(str2.match(pattern)[2]);
console.log(str3.match(pattern)[2]);
```

All of the 3 strings contain `am` substring, and this substring is following by age. So

- `(am\s)` matches `am` and a white space.
- `(\d{1,2})` matches age number. Because age can be 1 number or 2 number, that's why we need `{1,2}`

Comment: While obviously the Javascript demo should have the slashes because it's Javascript syntax, the `/` themselves are not part of the pattern. I suggest removing them from the first code block to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is always sentence with "years/year" you can try

```
\d+(?=[\s]?year)
```

which should match only numbers before word "year"

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That will capture the  age including the years in a capturing group.

Comment: @Thefourthbird damn you are right. Did not realized that **facepalm** correcting answer

Answer (score 0):

If the age can also be higher than 99, you could use:

`am (\d+) years`

The age is in the first capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UO9qXN/1)

```js
const strings = [
  " My username is Ajay. I am 20 years old.",
  " My username is atb00ker. I am 40 years old.",
  " My username is 394843. I am 22 years old.",
  " My username is 999999. I am 101 years old."
];
let pattern = /am (\d+) years/;
strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern)[1]);
});
```